# Close editing of rc resource files in Visual Studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm new to rc files and I'm used to being able to close files in VS and be prompted to save or not save.  This way I can quickly undo changes I've made to the file.  How do I get similar functionality for rc files?
Thanks.

Comment: There are two ways to edit an .rc file.  The normal way is with the built-in WYSIWIG resource editors, you don't directly see the changes to the .rc file.  Or you can edit it as a text file, requires right-click + Open With.  Saving the changes works the same way for both, type Ctrl+S or use File > Save.

Comment: Oh now I understand I can close the .rc files by right clicking on it in solution explorer -> View Code (F7) and then closing the file and selecting do not save.  Your posting is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't!  This is just one of the many infuriating things about both RC files and VS.

The only easy way I have found is to close the solution, discard the changes, and open the solution again.

I've got into the habit of editing resource files in a text editor most of the time.  That saves a lot of pain.  I also use Git, so it's often quite easy to revert any unstaged changes or cherry-pick those that I want to keep.  The bonus is when I modify the resource this way, VS will detect it and prompt me to reload the file, discarding any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found one tricky workaround to do what you asked for without solution reloading.

1. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` to open find dialog.
2. In the "Find what" field, type any text which should preset in the resource-file (for example, ID of some control).
3. Along with other files, records corresponding to your resource-file should be appeared in search results.
4. Double-click on any of this records. If the resource-file was opened (exactly as a resource file) at this stage, VS will inform you about this and ask you what to do: to close other editor or to leave all as it's. The first option is our goal.